# Redis mocha Test case issue

Tags: express, mocha.js, node-redis

I have one file call cache.js

```
var redisCache = redis.createClient(port, name);
redisCache.on("error", function(err) {
  logger.error("Error connecting to redis", err);
});

exports.setExp = function(key, timeLeft, data){
    redisCache.set(key, JSON.stringify(data), function (err, reply) {
      console.log("error "+err);
      console.log("reply "+reply);
      if(err) {
        console.log("error "+err.command + err.code);
        logger.info("This errror on set key related to node_redis");
      }
      if(reply == 'OK') {
        redisCache.expire(key, timeLeft, function (err, reply) {
          if(err) {
            logger.info("This errror on expire key related to node_redis");
          }
          if(reply === 1) {
            logger.info(key+" key expire time set as "+timeLeft+" successfully!");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Now I want to write the test case for the above setExp function but some how the node_redis aways return me the err as `null` and reply as `OK`

below is my test case.

```
var cache = require(path.join(__dirname,'..','/cache'));
describe('cache', function () {
  it('Cache #setExp() ', function (done) {
      var result = cache.setExp(undefined, 0, []);
        assert.equal('OK', results);
        done()
  })
})
```

IF I change the it should follow the below error I mention as per the [node_redis test case](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/master/test/commands/set.spec.js)

```
var result = cache.setExp('foo', 10, []);
```

it should return me the error called ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command

```
var result = cache.setExp(undefined, 0, []);
```

It should accept the below error log as 
    assert.equal(err.command, 'SET');

Please suggest me right way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking seems to be almost completely wrong here.

First of all, you're writing and using `setExp` as if it's a synchronous operation, but it isn't. It will return before the request is made to redis. It also never returns anything, so even if it was synchronous, `result` in your tests will always be `undefined.`

You need to redesign `setExp` as an asynchronous operation, either by using the `async` keyword, returning a promise, or having it accept a callback function.

Second of all, if you want to set an expiration on a Redis key, you should set it when you set the key itself, instead of setting the key with no expiration and then trying to add the expiration later. Otherwise you run the risk of the expiration setting failing, and then winding up with an orphaned key that never expires.

Here's an example, using node's [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to as [described in the node_redis docs](http://redis.js.org/#redis-a-nodejs-redis-client-usage-example-promises):

```
var redis = require('redis');
var {promisify} = require('util');
var redisCache = redis.createClient(port, name);
redisCache.on("error", function(err) {
  logger.error("Error connecting to redis", err);
});
var set = promisify(redisCache.set).bind(redisCache);

exports.setExp = function(key, timeLeft, data){
    return set(key, JSON.stringify(data), 'EX', timeLeft.toString(10))
        .then((reply) => {
            if (reply !== 'OK') throw new Error(reply);
            return reply;
        });
};
```

In your tests you'd do something like this:

```
var cache = require('../cache');

describe('cache', function () {
    it('Cache #setExp() ', function () {
      let key = 'some key';
      let timeLeft = 12345;
      let data = { foo: 'bar' };

      return cache.setExp(key, timeLeft, data)
        .then((result) => {
            assert.equal('OK', result);
        });
    });
});
```

Also, `results` and `result` are not the same thing. In your test case, there is no variable called `results`.

Oh, and don't do this:

```
var cache = require(path.join(__dirname,'..','/cache'));
```

`require` already supports paths relative to `__dirname`. Just do this:

```
var cache = require('../cache');
```